# Always Says Its The Wrong Answer?

Tags: python, random

I'm making a simple maths quiz its working fine except when I ask if its the correct answer it always says Incorrect if its correct or not.  I'm not sure where I went wrong any help on this would be appreciated.

```
import random
QuestN = 1
QNC = 0
CS = 0
WS = 0

while True:
    #Number Of Questions:
    QNC = QNC + 1
    if QNC == 10:
        break

    #Choosing The Questions
    ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    operation = random.choice(ops)

    #Simplifying The Operations
    if operation == "+":
        NEWOP = "+"
    elif operation == "-":
        NEWOP = "-"
    elif operation == "*":
        NEWOP = "x"
    elif operation == "/":
        NEWOP = "÷"

    #Asking The Questions
    print("Awnser This:")
    print(num1)
    print(NEWOP)
    print(num2)
    maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))

    #Awnsering The Questions
    PLAYERA = input(": ")
    print(maths)
    #Keeping Score
    if PLAYERA == maths:
        print("Correct")
        CS = CS +1 
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        WS = WS +1
    print()

#RESTART
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: this will only run `9` times because you are incrementing `QNC` before checking it. If you want `10` questions you should either move the increment line after the check line or change the check to `if QNC > 10:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `PLAYERA` will be a string. The variable `maths` will be an integer. In Python, `"7"` isn't the same thing as `7`, so your `if` statement will never be true.

You therefore need to this:

```
if int(PLAYERA) == maths:
    print("Correct")
    CS = CS +1
```

Note that this code will cause an error it the player's input isn't a number. You could avoid that by doing this instead:

```
if PLAYERA == str(maths):
    print("Correct")
    CS = CS +1
```

Comment: Since the user can theoretically type anything he or she wants, it's safer to do it this way: `if PLAYERA == str(maths):`

Comment: @killermonkey50 Good point, though safety doesn't seem to be too much of an issue given the liberal use of `eval`!

Comment: Frequent? He only uses it once! ;P